# Most Recommended approach to send periodic location information to server continuously in Android?

Tags: android, location

I am really amazed about this location aware system in android and not getting the consistent way to send periodic information to the server continuously. I wanted the application to be continuously running without fail even if the device is not switched off for month too. The problems I am facing are:

1. Service getting Killed after few days or hours.
2. If service is already there, the location information not being updated unless there are some kind of activity or movement on the device .

What might be the most recommended approaches? Currently I am creating a service to listen for location update on `onCreate()` method & send those data to server on `onStartCommand()` method. I have registered `AlarmManager()` from within service itself for 15 minutes periodicity to send location info...?

Comment: getting killed could mean that you running out of memory and read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041971/android-service-killed

Comment: `periodic` and `continuously` at one time ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android OS can kill a process at any time due to memory needs or other issues, so you have no guarantees that your process will continue to run. For similar reasons (limited resources on mobile devices), location services are optimized to reduce power consumption. One of these optimizations is to not provide location updates if you're not moving.

For a recommended approach, I'd go with this guy:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html