# Android Service Keeps Getting Killed?

Tags: java, android, service, background

I am currently writing an app that allows a parent to log the events that occurs from their childs phone. The logging takes place in a service which runs in the background. However, the service keeps dying after around a minute..

I dont know what other information you need to help, but any information is useful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are just binding to the service, then that's why your service is killed when the activity unbinds (Read that in the Docs). If you are using `.startService()` and then bind make sure in the `onStartCommand()` you return `START_STICKY`. You can read why and how here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

And yes, use `.startForground()` as well if you are doing something that user is aware of and shouldn't be killed in extreme cases.

Comment: @NikloaDespotoski I don't bind the service to the application. but the onStartCommand() returns START_STICKY and I have included .startForeground(1, new Notification()) in my onCreate().

Comment: Do you get any remote exception that is caught? Is the service killed due memory need?

Comment: Im sorry, but how would I be able to tell that? and noo, i dont catch a remote exception

Comment: Read hackbod's answer here, how the service is killed due memory need, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041971/android-service-killed

Answer (score 0):

try starting the Service as [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Reasons why a Service gets killed are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)